# How to make resource dll to describe device fonts?

Tags: fonts, driver, device-driver, drivers, wdk

The target driver I'm building is not a native driver but a minidriver working with Microsoft Universal Pinter Driver

According to DDK:

> Descriptions of these items [fonts in my case] are
>   placed in a resource DLL, as described
>   in the Platform SDK documentation.

It then goes on to say:

> In the printer's resource DLL, specify
>   .ufm files by using the RC_UFM
>   resource type, and specify .ifi files
>   by using the RC_FONT resource type.

Despite the reference to SDK, there is no information on how to actually place the .ifi font information inside a resource dll.

Can anyone please point out a way to do this ?

**Edit**

Yes, the printer contains resident fonts and I need to create a resource file that describes them.

So far I hit another road block, because apparently the font description file you have to compile into your resource dll cant be `.ifi` (even though the DDK says they can), they just don't work. However it works find with `.ufm` font description files.
The problem is we only have ifi files describing the device fonts but no umf...

Any advice ?

Comment: *To clarify....Is it that you have 'printer' resident fonts/resources you are trying to access? I have some knowledge with Minidriver development but want to make sure I'm answering the right question.*

Answer (score 1):

Go for ufm file, build ufm using print MDT (window DDK) and place their entry into resource file